# What makes a good sampling for K mean?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, sample-size, k-means

Say I have a csv files that I receive on a daily basis and each file contains 3,000 rows of data. I wish to create a K-Mean graph to uncover categories. How many items should I sample in order to get a good estimation of the presented data? Is there any standard sampling min/max?